# Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime

Tags: android

I was working on my app when this problem showed up. I don´t have any idea what that means: *Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)*. **Please help!**
This is my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JACooperationMobileApp">
    <activity android:name=".MemberNewsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".WeoponsBuyActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".WeoponsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FightsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Tell in the comments if you need more information to solve this problem.